# Display `ControlTipText` in front of the form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, tooltip

I am trying to insert a tooltip for a textbox on a form.

I am using the `ControlTipText` property of the textbox to do it.

The tooltip text is shown behind the form. How can I move the tooltip text forward and keep it in front of the form?

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a workaround in Excel 2013.  My Userform contained problematic RefEdit controls. Whenever a RefEdit control had focus all control tips appeared behind the UserForm. Switching the another control put the control tips back on top. 
Have a look at [PeltierTech's RefEdit Page.](https://peltiertech.com/using-refedit-controls-in-excel-dialogs/) There may be similar problems with other controls.